# Use MSAL in .NET C# to execute a custom policy flow in Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, policies

I am currently using OpenIdConnect to execute HTTP GET requests for my Azure B2C custom policies. For example here is the Unified SignInSignUp:

```
public static void Unified(HttpRequest Request, HttpResponse Response)
{
    string nonce = "defaultNonce";
    string clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aad.clientid"];
    string authUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aad.authUrl"];
    string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aad.redirecturi"];
    string unifiedPolicy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["aad.unifiedPolicy"];

    // build url for AAD auth and redirect to ourself 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}?", authUrl);
    sb.AppendFormat("p={0}", unifiedPolicy);
    sb.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", clientID);
    sb.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", redirectUri);
    sb.AppendFormat("&nonce={0}", nonce);
    sb.AppendFormat("&scope=openid");
    sb.AppendFormat("&response_type=id_token");
    sb.AppendFormat("&prompt=login");
    sb.AppendFormat("&response_mode=form_post");

    // redirect to auth via AAD (and then redirect back to ourself)
    Response.Redirect(sb.ToString(), true);
}
```

I would like to use MSAL instead but am having trouble finding a C# .NET sample that executes an HTTP GET request like I am doing with OpenIdConnect. My current technique returns the id_token just fine, but I would like to take advantage of MSAL's capabilities like caching etc.

Is such a sample around?

Comment: Have you referred to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations?

Comment: Yes, I had seen that, and it is somewhat helpful. Today I found https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi which was helpful as well, especially the files in the TaskWebApp/Utils/ folder.

Comment: That's great. If you have found what you want, you can add an answer and this post can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as a comment, but the system indicated it was too long. So I would like to answer my question, since I did find some sample code (mentioned in my comment to self above) that helped me get started ~using~ MSAL.net. However I am having a number of issues (e.g. when I call my edit profile custom policy the set of claims I get is are very incomplete, using OpenIdConnect I get all my claims) and questions and will probably post another questions that is more specific, laying out my requirements. I really just need the id_token (and the OpenId Connect code I posted above was great for that), not the access or refresh tokens, and all I really need to do is validate that id_token and implement a KMSI (keep me signed in) strategy. I have added the B2C KMSI in my custom sign-in policy, but can't see how to query it in my web (asp.net web forms) web project. Currently (without using Azure) I have a "remember me" checkbox on my website and I write a persistent cookie with a rolling 30-day expiry with encrypted data in it and everything works as required; I am trying to move to Azure B2C and keep that all working.Also for validating the token I am currently using some code I found in a post here that uses low-level code (System.Security.Cryptography namespace) and it validates well, but I don't see how to validate the few claims that are recommended in documentation I have seen. So I will create a new post that inquires about all that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented user signin without redirecting to b2clogin page?